# Why does style.display change the size of my div when set to 'block'?

Tags: javascript, css

I have 3 divs each one containing a google timeline chart.
3 buttons to toggle between each of the 3 divs.
I use javascript to hide the 2 other divs and show one.
If I set all of the divs to show they all have the same length and width.
However, when I start toggling in between them, only the one that started as display: 'block' keeps the same size and the rest become much smaller when toggled to show.
I've already tried setting the div size in my javascript functions, didn't work.
When I inspect element on one of the toggled divs it shows 400px for width.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['timeline']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline2');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    id: 'President'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'Start'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'End'
  });
  dataTable.addRows([
    ['Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
    ['Adams', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
    ['Jefferson', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1809, 2, 4)]
  ]);

  chart.draw(dataTable);
}

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2);

function drawChart2() {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline3');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    id: 'President'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'Start'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'End'
  });
  dataTable.addRows([
    ['Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
    ['Adams', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
    ['Jefferson', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1809, 2, 4)]
  ]);

  chart.draw(dataTable);
}

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart3);

function drawChart3() {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline4');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    id: 'President'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'Start'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'End'
  });
  dataTable.addRows([
    ['Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
    ['Adams', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
    ['Jefferson', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1809, 2, 4)]
  ]);

  chart.draw(dataTable);
}

function showMonth() {
  document.getElementById('timeline3').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('timeline4').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('timeline2').style.display = 'block';
}

function showWeek() {
  document.getElementById('timeline3').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('timeline4').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('timeline2').style.display = 'none';
}

function showDay() {
  document.getElementById('timeline3').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('timeline4').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('timeline2').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
#timeline2 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 1791px;
  background-color: red;
}

#timeline3 {
  display: none;
  height: 300px;
  width: 1791px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#timeline4 {
  display: none;
  height: 300px;
  width: 1791px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<button class='monthb' onclick="showMonth()">Month</button>
<button class='weekb' onclick="showWeek()">Week</button>
<button class='dayb' onclick="showDay()">Day</button>
<br />
<div id="timeline2"></div>
<div id="timeline3"></div>
<div id="timeline4"></div>
```

Comment: Please consider applying a `background-color` or some other indicator to your `<div>`s to show the size change you've mentioned. Using *Inspect Element*, they all appear the same size for me.

Comment: *each one containing a google timeline chart* -->actually you shared empty divs so not sure we can reproduce your issue with

Comment: not sure why the snippet is not running tho, i added more context

Comment: Take a look at the `<div dir="ltr" ... ></div>` element. I would imagine that the chart's width is determined by its container. Given that the container is not visible when the width is determined, it instead uses a default value. This would explain why the first one, which is visible initially, is the only one to receive the proper width of its container.

Comment: I think the div have the same width, but not the charts.

Did you try to set all your div in display:block, load the charts and THAN ONLY hide them ? Charts are loaded in divs that have no width, because hidden.

Comment: @iguypouf yes i did, and doing so worked perfectly with the right sizes.

Comment: @TylerRoper Got ur point. Is there a way to set the container's width initially even if the chart is not visible?

Comment: So if you dont want the risk that the 3 charts may be visible a few milliseconds, either superpose your div in absolute position and play with opacity; or set opacity to transparent for the container of all div, and only display it when everything is loaded.

Comment: @iguypouf life savior! it worked. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the chart's width is determined by examining the width of its container. However if the container isn't visible, it cannot properly determine the width.

Consider hiding the div *after* each `chart.draw()`. (These could afford to be refactored to remove some duplicate logic but for sake of the demonstration, I've simply added it to the two charts that are supposed to start as hidden.)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['timeline']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline2');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    id: 'President'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'Start'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'End'
  });
  dataTable.addRows([
    ['Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
    ['Adams', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
    ['Jefferson', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1809, 2, 4)]
  ]);

  chart.draw(dataTable);
}

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2);

function drawChart2() {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline3');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    id: 'President'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'Start'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'End'
  });
  dataTable.addRows([
    ['Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
    ['Adams', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
    ['Jefferson', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1809, 2, 4)]
  ]);

  chart.draw(dataTable);
  document.getElementById('timeline3').style.display = 'none';
}

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart3);

function drawChart3() {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline4');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    id: 'President'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'Start'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'End'
  });
  dataTable.addRows([
    ['Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
    ['Adams', new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
    ['Jefferson', new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1809, 2, 4)]
  ]);

  chart.draw(dataTable);
  document.getElementById('timeline4').style.display = 'none';
}

function showMonth() {
  document.getElementById('timeline3').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('timeline4').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('timeline2').style.display = 'block';
}

function showWeek() {
  document.getElementById('timeline3').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('timeline4').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('timeline2').style.display = 'none';
}

function showDay() {
  document.getElementById('timeline3').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('timeline4').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('timeline2').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
#timeline2 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 1791px;
}

#timeline3 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 1791px;
}

#timeline4 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 1791px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<button class='monthb' onclick="showMonth()">Month</button>
<button class='weekb' onclick="showWeek()">Week</button>
<button class='dayb' onclick="showDay()">Day</button>
<br />
<div id="timeline2"></div>
<div id="timeline3"></div>
<div id="timeline4"></div>
```

Comment: @Karl-Joey G. Chami - Thanks for the edit, not sure how I lost my changes!